# How to distributively compute a secret of that form $\mathsf{s=sk\cdot g^a}$?

Tags: secret-sharing

Is there a standard way to distributively compute secrets shares such that any $t+1$ combination out of $n$ of them constructs the secret $\mathsf{s=sk\cdot g^a}$, for a generator $\mathsf{g} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathsf{sk,a}$ chosen uniformly at random from $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: If $sk, a$ are uniform and independently distributed (and $p$ is prime), then the distribution of $sk \cdot g^a$ is uniform within $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Are you asking how to distribute shares of a random value?

Comment: Shares that their reconstruction will have the form  of $\mathsf{s}$. Nobody should learn $sk$ or $a$. But in the end n parties should be able to compute shares of them such that any $t$ out $n$ of that shares can compute $skg^a$

Answer (score 6):

I assume that your question relates to sharing a secret specifically of this form. Furthermore, you want to guarantee this even if the dealer is not trusted and may try to share a secret of a different form. Otherwise, you could just use any secret sharing (or verifiable secret sharing) scheme.

However, note that $s$ as you wrote actually does not have any special form. Specifically, since $a$ is uniformly random, $sk\cdot g^a$ is just a uniformly random element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus, as you have worded your question, you can use *any* secret sharing scheme for which the domain of the secret is $\mathbb{Z}_p$.